# @PreUpdate never fired in Wildfly 8 / JPA 2.1

Tags: jpa, jboss, wildfly

I am experiencing the strange effect, that `@PreUpdate` hook never fires. Code:

```
@PrePersist
@PreUpdate
public void prePersist() {
    if (getCreated() == null) {
        setCreated(new Date());
        setCreatedBy(LoginHolder.getUser());
    }
    setLastModified(new Date());
    setModifiedBy(LoginHolder.getUser());

}
```

Although hibernate logs an update to my (existing) entity, only the @Prepersist fires on new 
items. Have I missed something?

Comment: Yes, you have missed something, and namely to show us the code that fires the EntityManager operations.

Comment: Sorry for the delay and thanks for Your reply. The entity manager operations are implicitely performed by wildfly on the end of a transaction, so apparently there is no more code i could show except the Entity Instantiation and the entityManager.persist(o);. The prepersist hook correclty fires, but the preupdate method doesn't although it should, even if i modify an existing object i fetch with a entityManager.find().

Comment: So you do `persist()` and `merge()` in different sessions, with different EntityManagers? Also show us how you inject/instantiate your EntityManager.

Comment: no, i only use entityManager.persist(). JBoss does the rest when I am leaving my transaction context. If I modify the data, later in another transaction, the preUpdate hook never fires on the end of my transaction, although I can see the data changes on the database. The same code example always worked in a JBoss 7, but it does not in Wildfly - which carries a newer Hibernate version.